# Double click on ribbon save button

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, ribbon

When a user add a new list item in a list, if he performs a double click on the ribbon's save button he founds that 2 list items have been inserted.
How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: really? I couldn't reproduce this behavior. Can you show us exactly how to reproduce it? (is it a doc lib or list? where exactly does your user click on? is it a modal or non-modal form?)

Comment: SharePoint 2013, a list (not doc.lib.), non-modal form. Double click on "Save button" in the ribbon (the save button in the form has no problem)

Answer (score 0):

That's because your sharepoint has a delay to write to the database.

how to solve: With JavaScript in the onClick() event of the button, hide button to hide(), so the user will not be able to double clik.

Hope it helped.